# Read .mdb file using golang on mac os with apple silicon architecture

Tags: go, ms-access, adodb, cgo

I had an issue while reading .mdb file in golang on macOS with apple silicon.

This is the source code that I use:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    _ "runtime/cgo"

    accessdbwe "github.com/bennof/AccessDBwE"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-adodb"
)

func main() {
    _, err := accessdbwe.Open("adodb", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=PetStore2002.mdb;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to open mdb file: %T, %q", err, err)
    }

    println("success ping mdb")
}
```

When the code run, the `err` variable is not `nil` but `err.String()` is empty. So I'm very confused about what is the error.

I can run the same code successfully on a windows laptop. Is there anything missed in my code?

Note: I've checked my .mdb file using mdbtools, mdb viewer and ms access on windows and the file is valid.

This my go version:

```
go version go1.20.2 darwin/arm64
```

Comment: If you want Access anywhere but Windows, you need to use ODBC and mdbtools (or Jackcess/UCanAccess when working with Java is easy). The standard Access oledb and ODBC drivers are Windows-exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Reading .mdb file on non-Windows is not supported by the package `github.com/mattn/go-adodb` as of now.

#### Why it's not supported on non-Windows?

`github.com/mattn/go-adodb` is a "Microsoft ADODB driver conforming to the built-in database/sql interface", which depends on `github.com/go-ole/go-ole` to communicate with the database.

The underlying package `github.com/go-ole/go-ole` provides "Go bindings for Windows COM using shared libraries instead of cgo", which does not support non-Windows as of now. Here is the statement from the [README.md](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole/blob/master/README.md) file of the package:

> It is also not currently possible to test the library on Linux, since COM API is specific to Windows and it is not currently possible to run a COM server on Linux or even connect to a remote COM server.

#### Why `err.String()` is empty?

Regarding the empty error message, that's because the error is an [ole.OleError](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole/blob/bae8d7883a5dd318b04554a1e4a202ad24abddc9/error.go#L4). In the case when the description is empty, it calls `errstr(int(v.hr))` to convert error code to string. And on non-Windows, the [errstr func](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole/blob/master/error_func.go) just returns an empty string.

You can use a debugger to find out the details of the error. It's most likely that the error code is `0x80004001`, which is `E_NOTIMPL: Not implemented` (see [Common HRESULT Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values)).

[image]

Comment: i tried using parallel using window 11 and it's not working too, can you explain why? or the package `github.com/go-ole/go-ole` only works on native windows?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a Window 11 running on Parallels, so I can't test it myself. What's the error have you encountered?

Comment: I would assume that you are running Windows 11 Arm in Parallels on macOS with apple silicon. Have you found a "Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable" that supports Windows Arm? [The one I found](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255) only lists two files for x86 and x64 separately.

Comment: oh i see, maybe i used windows 11 Arm since it installed default by parallel and running on Apple ARM, so i've experienced the same condition with mac os